# error.hbs: Can't set headers after they are sent on basic passport authentication using auth0

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, auth0

I am using auth0 for authentication. The code at the bottom of the question works absolutely fine except the fact that it shows following error at the server console:

```
GET /callback?code=uIOyxyvGN9XBICQy 200 2941.858 ms - 1912
Error: /media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/views/error.hbs: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:695:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at fn (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:929:10)
    at /media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:93:9
    at done (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/async.js:74:20)
    at /media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:88:18
    at /media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:69:11
    at done (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/async.js:74:20)
    at /media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:64:20
    at fs.js:268:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

The code snippet I was talking about:

```
var passport = require('passport');

router.get('/callback',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '/url-if-something-fails' }),
  function(req, res) {
    if (!req.user) {
      throw new Error('user null');
    }
    res.send(req.user)
    //res.redirect("/user");
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? How can we fix it?

Comment: is this res.redirect commented or not?

Comment: can you use **return** instead of **throw** in if condition?